# How can i attach my custom keyboard which is built in react native to any other android mobile?

Tags: android, react-native, native, custom-keyboard

How can i integrate my custom keyboard which is made in react native into any other android phone because i have no skills about native code ??
I tried and tried but there is no solutuon to this so tell me how can i do that easily?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.